# Mongodb group by pair

Tags: mongodb

I have got a data like this :  [DATA](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g7r2CkSu7HH?fbclid=IwAR3M3JSndv0t1jepRcXJxu24QGyB2y6fjBZcR4n1mOB8uqHzwVfwB2rTYvs)  , I try to group by domaine names , I want a result to be look like that :

```
[{     
{       "domain": "gmail_com_"
    "A": 3
    "B": 5
    "C": 3 },
............
}]
```

Where A,B are the lenght of the list for the domain names that match,and C is the size of duplicated ip address .But as you see in the result if the domain names is present in more than two diff timestamp it only group with the two first one, and I want to group two by two with all the possiblities, in my exemple , facebook is present in 3 diff tsp so we should have three diff pair. if someone can help me. 
thnx

Comment: So if a domain has 10 documents in the input data, you want 90 output documents, one for each possible pair?

Comment: @Joe yes that's it

Comment: External links have a tendency to change or go away, which would rob this question of quite a bit of value.  Please put a sample of your data and your query in the question.

Comment: I suspect this is the reason someone downvoted your question, even though they didn't bother to comment.  If you edit your question to add this information, they may reverse that downvote.

Answer (score 0):

To get every possible pair of two discreet values from a series of documents, you will need to:

- gather the values into an array
- assign an index of some sort to identify each
- duplicate the array
- unwind both duplicates
- eliminate pairs with the same index

An aggregation pipeline might look like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$group:{
     _id:"$domain",
     list:{$push:"$ip"}
  }},
  {$project:{
     numberedList:{
        $reduce: {
            input: "$list",
            initialValue: {a:[],c:0},
            in:{ 
                a:{$concatArrays:["$$value.a",[{ip:"$$this",idx:"$$value.c"}]]},
                c:{$add:["$$value.c",1]}
  }}}}},
  {$project:{
      left:"$numberedList",
      right:"$numberedList"
  }},
  {$unwind:"$left"},
  {$unwind:"$right"},
  {$match:{$expr:{$ne:["$left.idx","$right.idx"]}}}
])
```

This should leave you with the domain name in `_id` and a pair of results in `left` and `right`, which you can then process as needed.

Comment: sorry but it's seems that your query is syntactically incorrect (https://mongoplayground.net/p/2zHuhU03N6-?fbclid=IwAR2b-NTY7s2FkQl3VBg9EUWsdkEQZLVdaK-xs9xBTcJdzkOTP39buOO5B7c)

Comment: Yep, typo, I missed a closing brace in one stage.  Fixed now.

Comment: sorry but when I test I got no document found

Comment: If you could put some sample data in the question, I'll be able to adjust the query to fit your data.